# Is it possible to 'subscribe' to the Cache Cannel and add custom actions

Tags: 2013-sp1, cache, cache-channel-service

We are using the 'RMI CacheChannel' in a Tridion 2013 SP1 environment. I was wondering if it is possible to 'listen' to the Cache Channel and do custom actions on content invalidation. So like an Event System for cache invalidation.

side note: We are soon upgrading to SDL Web 8. So if Web 8 offers the solution we can wait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2013 SP1 the Cache Channel messages were not a public API, and that hasn't changed yet in Web 8 either.

I don't think you can do much with the RMI at all actually, but when you change to JMS there are some possibilities. See for example Mihai's blog on how to hook into the messages using a JMS listener http://yatb.mitza.net/2014/07/custom-cache-invalidation-using-jms.html

Please note that the JMS messages are also not considered public API, which means that your JMS listener is not supported and the message format may change in a future release, so calculate possible rework during upgrades in.

Comment: Hi Bart, thank you for the usefull information!